Why does default operator <=> give us operator == for free but custom implementation does not?
I tried two variants of defining operator<=>,
variant A uses = default. In consequence I am able to use operator ==.
But if I implement operator<=> by hand in variant B, the comparison x1 == x2 stops working.
Why is this the case? It it stated this way in the C++20 standard? I could not find any explanation so far.
For me operator<=> is a function, whether it is defaulted or not. I expect no difference between A and B.
Code:
#include <iostream>

class X {
public:
    int y;

/*A*/    inline std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const X& another) const = default;    
/*B*/    //inline std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const X& another) const { return y <=> another.y; }
};

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    
    X x1;
    x1.y = 5;
    
    X x2;
    x2.y = 7;
    
    cout << "x1 == x2:   " << (x1 == x2) << endl;
    cout << "x1 == x2:   " << (x1 <=> x2 == 0) << endl;

    return 0;
}


Yeah, that's just the language rule. Defaulted <=> also gives you defaulted ==, but non-defaulted <=> does not give you anything else.

See this answer in the dupe that explains exactly this in detail. What is the <=> ("spaceship", three-way comparison) operator in C++?

https://godbolt.org/z/aY6vdK7q9

The why? is because using a non-defaulted <=> for == would generate an inefficient == (it'd likely be doing twice as much comparison work as necessary).
